# Thermal expansion: why in Celsius and not in Kelvin?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, units, si-units

When dealing with thermal expansion problems I've encountered a situation where I must calculate the change in length of an iron bridge 2km long if the amplitude of temperature changes by 40ºC, considering $\alpha_L = 1.25\times10^{-5} 1/K$.

I used $\Delta L = \alpha_L L_0 \Delta T = 1.25 \times 10^{-5} \times 2 \times 10^3 \times (40 + 273.15) \approx 8 m$. But the right answer is $1m$ according to the solutions. I discovered what I did wrong: the temperature should be in Celsius degrees, not in Kelvin (should be $40$, not $313.15$).

But this is counter intuitive to me. Why must it be in Celsius to give the correct answer? Shouldn't it be in Kelvin to give the right units considering $[\alpha_L] =n [K^{-1}]$?

Comment: this is an affine space vs vector space problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is perfectly fine in Kelvins too. You have just mistaken the formula.

Basically, when you see a $\Delta,$ there is *very* high chance that this is a subtraction of two things.

What the question is really telling you, is that $\Delta T=40^\circ\text C=40\,\text K$

This is true because, say, assuming you had $a-b=40^\circ\text C,$ that will also equal $(a+c)-(b+c)=40\,\text K$, where $c=273.15\,\text K$

Comment: Is there no notation to distinguish between temperature point, and temperature difference?  Is the question "Convert 40 Kelvin to Fahrenheit." forever ambiguous?

Comment: it does not seem to appear often enough to warrant work into resolving it

Answer (score 5):

$\Delta T$ is the difference of temperatures - it doesn't matter, whether it is in Celcius or Kelvin, since they differ only by the origin of the scale: $$\Delta T =T_1-T_2=t_1+273.15 - (t_2+273.15)=t_1-t_2=\Delta t$$

Answer (score 1):

An object at 0 deg Celsius is at 273.15 Kelvin.
An object at 1 deg Celsius is at 274.15 Kelvin.

If we increase the temperature by 1 deg Celsius we increased it by 1 Kelvin, not by 274.15 Kelvin. Otherwise heating up ice (273.15 Kelvin) by 1 degree Celsius would make it a temperature of 547.3 Kelvin, which it obviously doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

The formula for thermal expansion should include the **change** in temperature and since a change in temperature by $1^{\circ}\rm C$ is the same as $1\,\rm K$ it matters not which unit of temperature you use.
One Celsius degree is an interval of 1 K. - [NIST - SI Units – Temperature](https://www.nist.gov/pml/owm/si-units-temperature)